# How to set section header/footer margins in Eureka without creating custom classes

Tags: swift, eureka-forms

I am using the Eureka framework and recently added code to allow for edge to edge cell separators. With this, all the form elements need to have a margin defined otherwise they start at the very left of the screen.

Is there a way to adjust the left/right margins of the Section header/footer similarly to a cell? I am trying to avoid using custom classes for every section/header title.

I tried looking at the source code to see how the view is created, but I don't see anywhere where it defines the x-coordinate or left/right margins, etc. I also don't see any properties that I could set to accomplish this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
            +++ Section(){section in
                var footer = HeaderFooterView<UITableViewHeaderFooterView>(.Class)
                footer.onSetupView = {view, _, _ in
                    view.preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = false
                    view.layoutMargins.left = 50
                    view.layoutMargins.right = 50
                    view.contentView.preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = false
                    view.contentView.layoutMargins.top = 10
                    view.contentView.layoutMargins.left = 50
                    view.textLabel?.text = "This is a test footer message."
                    view.textLabel?.layoutMargins.top = 10
                    view.textLabel?.font = UIFont.preferredFontForTextStyle("Footnote")
                }
                section.header = HeaderFooterView<ALogoView>(HeaderFooterProvider.Class)
                section.footer = footer
                }
```

Edit: I've tried the above, but it does not work. If you put in a long string, it moves up into the parent section's rows.

Edit2: I've come up with the following

```
class GenericHeader: UIView {

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    self.preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = false
    let textView = UILabel()
    textView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width - 30, height: 20 )
    textView.text = "This is  a very very very long title, This is  a very very very long title, This is  a very very very long title, This is  a very very very long title, This is  a very very very long title, This is  a very very very long title Let's add some more stuff here to see how it handles."
    textView.numberOfLines = 0
    textView.textAlignment = .Justified
    textView.font = UIFont.preferredFontForTextStyle(UIFontTextStyleBody)
    textView.textColor = UIColor(red:0.47, green:0.47, blue:0.49, alpha:1.0)
    textView.frame = textView.bounds
    textView.sizeToFit()
    self.addSubview(textView)
    //self.frame = CGRect(x: -15, y: -3, width: textView.bounds.width - 16, height: textView.bounds.height)
    self.bounds = CGRect(x: -15, y: -3, width: textView.bounds.width - 16, height: textView.bounds.height)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
}
```

I'm using this in my form:

```
+++ Section() {
    $0.header = HeaderFooterView<GenericHeader>(HeaderFooterProvider.Class)
    $0.footer = HeaderFooterView<GenericFooter>(HeaderFooterProvider.Class)
}
```

How can I pass along a string when the Header/Footer classes are instantiated so that I don't have to write a million different classes/views with different text?

Comment: Hi, did it worked? Do you have a sample image on how it looks? Apppreciate it

Answer (score 0):

I have added table view cell margings by doing this n each row....

```
TextRow.defaultCellSetup = { cell, row in
    cell.preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = false
    cell.layoutMargins.left = 0
    cell.contentView.preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = false
    cell.contentView.layoutMargins.left = 50
}

ButtonRow.defaultCellSetup = { cell, row in
    cell.preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = false
    cell.layoutMargins.left = 0
    cell.indentationLevel = 5
}
```

Look into this issue that explains a little bit more...
https://github.com/xmartlabs/Eureka/issues/438

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I'm actually the author of the github thread, and there is no defaultCellSetup for section headers and footers. It uses a different method of rendering these UI elements. I have created a new issue on github because the .onSetupView doesn't seem to take any margin settings.

Comment: To add margins to Section headers/footers you will have to implement a custom view asz explained in this readme section: https://github.com/xmartlabs/Eureka#section-header-and-footer

Comment: Code above is to set up row margins in case default table view headers fit your needs. If you need more customization on the section header you should go for custom views.

Comment: The problem I run into w/ custom views is that I can't get it to auto-resize the frame depending on the content of the string. All I want to do is just allow for the string to wrap around and fit the width of the screen (minus margins I set) and automatically resize the height depending on how many lines it needs to display the string.

Comment: I'm posting an update to the github thread. Would appreciate you taking a look at it and letting me know how I can pass along the title string to it. Everything else I've managed to do! :)